# Django field not passing through serializer

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-firestore

Using the Django REST Framework 2.2, I have a `Person` model as follows in **`models.py:`**:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length = 20, primary_key = True, blank = True)
    name = Models.CharField(max_length = 1024, blank = True)
    values = {}

    @staticmethod
    def create_person(personData):
        person = Person(
            name = personData.get("name", "Unknown"),
            values = personData.get("values", {}),
        )

        return person
```

All data is stored in a Firestore database for saving and retrieving data via the REST API. Before new entries are made into the database, a serializer is used to validate incoming POST data.

The route `/person` takes POST request data and runs it by the `PersonCreateSerializer` in
**`views.py:`**

```py
def create_person(request):
    """
        Route: /person
        Method: POST
    """
    try:
        print(request.data)
        # Above print outputs:
        # <QueryDict: {'name': ['John Doe'], 'values': ['{ "height": 180 }']}>

        serializer = PersonCreateSerializer(data = request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception = True)
        person = Person.create_person(request.data)
        ...
    except APIException as exception:
            return JsonResponse(exception.APIError, status = exception.status)
```

**`serializers.py:`**

```py
class PersonCreateSerializer(CreateModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = "__all__"
    
    def validate(self, data):
        print(data)
        # Above print outputs:
        # OrderedDict([('name', 'John Doe')])
        # Notice missing 'values' field.

        if not data.get("values"): # Ensure we have a values field within the data.
            raise APIException("ERROR_MISSING_FIELD", "Missing required field 'values'.", 400)

        return data
```

The problem is however any value provided for the `values` dictionary is discarded when the serializer `validate()` function receives it.

**POST Payload:**

[image: Post Payload Image]

My question is why is the dictionary received from the POST request not received by the serializer so it can be parsed? What is the correcy way to create dictionary fields in Django?

Sent to Serializer:

```py
<QueryDict: {'name': ['John Doe'], 'values': ['{ "height": 180 }']}>
```

Received by Serializer:

```py
OrderedDict([('name', 'John Doe')])
```

### The problem with `JSONField` and `HStoreField`

I have looked at alternatives mentioned such as `HStoreField` and `JSONField` however this data is being stored in a Firestore database and the key-value association needs to be retained rather than it being stored as a plain JSON string.

Because the data is being stored in Firestore, the structure of the dictionary array needs to be retained as a map in the database, this allows it to be indexed and queried with Firestore queries.

[image: img]

If we use `JSONField`, this simply converts the value to a string and removes this functionality.

[image: img]

Comment: Serializers do count those class variables as model fields, you need to use a `JSONField`

Comment: Like Ersain and NixonSparrow mentioned, `values` is not a model field. Hence, the serializer discards it. If you want to store `values` in the database, you have to make it a model field, using for example, `JSONField` as suggested.

Comment: @Mekicha The problem with this is the data then gets stored as a JSON string within the database, and thus cannot be indexed or searched accordingly via Firebase queries; this is why the key-value structure needs to be retained.

Comment: See additional explanation added to end of question.

Comment: I see. Your serializer should inherit from the base serializer instead, and then define the fields in the serializer by yourself. Instead of subclassing `ModelSerializer`. Let me know if that makes sense

Comment: I am unsure how to go about inheriting a serializer and adding fields, could you provide an example of this?

Comment: Currently your serializer inherits from `ModelCreateSerializer`. You will need to inherit from `Serializer` instead. I can write out a full example as an answer if you want. You can see an example here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#declaring-serializers

Comment: By the way, I don't understand this part:       `person= Person.create_person(request.data)` Can you post the `create_person` method of your model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241647/discussion-between-skully-and-mekicha).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to make use of the [`django-dictionaryfield`](https://pypi.org/project/django-dictionaryfield/) module, this provides a Dictionary field type that can be used for converting to and from all array types, such as dictionaries and lists.

Without a field declared in the `model.py`, the serializer ignores it since it isn't considered part of the model itself, therefore using a custom `DictionaryField` model allows it to be stored as a Django model field.

### Django DictionaryField Setup

1. Install the module into your project:

   ```sh
   $ pip install django-dictionaryfield
   ```
2. Add `dictionaryfield` into your `INSTALLED_APPS` in the Django configuration file:

   ```py
   INSTALLED_APPS = (
       ...
       "dictionaryfield",
   )
   ```

### Model Class

Use the `DictionaryField` for fields that should be arrays.

```py
from django.db import models
from dictionaryfield import DictionaryField

class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length = 20, primary_key = True, blank = True)
    name = Models.CharField(max_length = 1024, blank = True)
    values = DictionaryField(default = {})

    @staticmethod
    def create_person(personData):
        person = Person(
            name = personData.get("name", "Unknown"),
            values = personData.get("values", {}),
        )

        return person
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because `values` is not a field. It is just a class variable.

Serializer filters the data by fields you have pointed to. And you pointed to `__all__` which means *all fields* in model.

You can try:

```
fields = ['name', 'values']
```

And if it didn't work, make a function and pass it "as a field":

```
# models.py

class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length = 20, primary_key = True, blank = True)
    name = Models.CharField(max_length = 1024, blank = True)
    values = {}

    def get_values(self):
        return self.values

# serializers.py

class PersonCreateSerializer(CreateModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['name', 'get_values']
```

Comment: Just tried both approaches, unfortunately `values` is still not received by the serializer.

Comment: Maybe try to change to `ModelSerializer` instead of `CreateModelSerializer`.

Comment: I've just created similar situation and it works for me. Where do you import that serializer from?

Comment: `from rest_framework import serializers`, and then using `serializers.ModelSerializer`. For clarity, what Django version are you using?

Comment: I use django==4.0.

Comment: I am using 2.2.10, so this could be a feature added later on instead.

Comment: Hi @Skully, please consider accepting the answer if it's working in a later version of Django. Thanks

Comment: @FaridShumbar This does not answer my question, as stated in my original question I am looking for a solution that is specifically in this version.